# Using inputRowSelect in a dynamic dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, row, dynamic-tables

Inside the dataTable dynamically creates a dataTable with the records, how can I get the number of rows for each dataTable that was created?

My Table:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.tableId}"
    var="tableIdInfo" rows="10">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="id_date"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{tableIdInfo.id_date}"
            styleClass="outputText">
            <hx:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
        </h:outputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.tableList}" var="tInfo">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                </f:facet>
                <hx:inputRowSelect value="#{bean.rows}">
                </hx:inputRowSelect>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputText"
                        value="Date create"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{tInfo.cDate}">
                    <hx:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `tableId` is a list of data.

then add a column for getting row numbers.

```
       <h:column>
            <!-- display currently selected row number -->
            <f:facet name="header">No</f:facet>
            #{bean.tableId.rowIndex + 1}

        </h:column>
```

Comment: How can I get the row number through cheksboks (`#{bean.rows}`)?

Comment: here tableId is the list so bean.tableId.rowIndex will return each row numbers for each iteration.